# Is it possible to find which userControl are visible in a flowlayoutPanel

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I have a `FlowLayoutPanel` that I add 50 `UserControl` to dynamically. The panel  is positioned vertically and each user control has some labels that are read-only.

I use `this.KeyPreview = true;`
in the form so I can use the event handler `Form1_KeyUp` to catch `keyUp` event.
In this event handler, I catch the navigation buttons <kbd>↑</kbd>, <kbd>↓</kbd>, <kbd>→</kbd>, <kbd>←</kbd>, <kbd>PageUp</kbd> and <kbd>PageDown</kbd>.

When I click the navigation button <kbd>↑</kbd> the previous `UserControl` is selected in the panel and when click <kbd>↓</kbd> the next `UserControl` is selected. This works good.

The customer want also to be able to use <kbd>PageUp</kbd> and <kbd>PageDown</kbd> which I catch in the event handler `Form1_KeyUp` as I mentioned before.

I hope that I can find which `UserControl` that are visible. Assume `UserControl` with index 1,2,3,4 are visible in the panel then I can select user control at index 1 when I use <kbd>PageUp</kbd> and user control at index 4 when I click <kbd>PageDown</kbd>.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: you mean "visible"  if at least one pixel of a control can be seen?

Comment: Each control has a Boolean (get/set) Visible property. You can loop through controls or just test Control.Visible

Comment: Not for nothing but please take a moment to take the [Tour].  Accepting answers and upvoting Q&A which you find helpful helps other users find good answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use such code:

```
var controls = container.Controls.Cast<Control>().OrderBy(x => x.Top);
var visibles = controls.Where(l => container.ClientRectangle.IntersectsWith(l.Bounds));
var top = visibles.FirstOrDefault();
var bottom = visibles.LastOrDefault();
```

In above code, I first ordered controls of container by `Top` of them. Then using [`IntersectsWith`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.rectangle.intersectswith(v=vs.110).aspx) I found those controls that their bounds has intersection with client rectangle of container which means those controls are visible.

Since the list is ordered by `Top` property of controls, the first item is the visible one at top of container and the last item is the visible one at bottom of container.

**Note**

- Instead of `Cast<Control>` you can use `OfType<YourUserControl>`.
- Instead of `OrderBy(x => x.Top)` you can use `OrderByDescending(x => container.Controls.IndexOf(x))`
- You can bring the top control into view using `container.ScrollControlIntoView(top);` or the bottom control `container.ScrollControlIntoView(bottom);`
- If you have a `FlowLayoutPanel` with `AutoScroll=True` and `FlowDirection=TopDown` and `WrapContents=False` then you can use a `Panel` instead, just when adding user controls, set `Dock=Top` for them.

Comment: Yes I use your suggested code and I had to add additional code do navigate up or down in the flowlayoutpanel depending of the height of the form.

Comment: @tony I believe you don't need to use height of form and instead you can use such code `container.ScrollControlIntoView(someControl); ` to bring `someControl` into view. Here `container` is your `FlowLayoutPanel`.

Comment: By the way, if the flow which you need is just vertical and your `FlowLayoutPanel` has scrollbars, then I believe you can easily use a `Panel` instead and then when adding your user controls, `Dock` them to `Top`. See an example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32887572/3110834).

Comment: Also using a `FlowLayouPanel` with `AutoScroll=True` and `FlowDirection=TopDown` and `WrapContents=False` I could bring the control into view using `container.ScrollControlIntoView(someControl);`.

Answer (score 0):

if I understand you correctly , this is what you meant

```
 public List<Control> GetvisibleControls(Control parent)
            {
                List<Control> returnList = new List<Control>();
                foreach(Control child in parent.Controls)
                {
                    if (child.Location.X < parent.Width && child.Location.Y < parent.Height)
                        returnList.Add(child);
                }
                return returnList;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

If by visible you mean, Visible property is true, use  'Shannon Holsinger' answer:

If you mean at least one pixel of a control can be seen, loop on all controls, and use this answer for checking if the control is visible

[C# winform check if control is physicaly visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4747935/c-sharp-winform-check-if-control-is-physicaly-visible)